# How to maintain UI state across model changes?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I have a CollaborativeList of objects that have a state of being selected in the UI. One action the user can take results in one object being removed and a number of objects being added in its place. I have handlers for ValuesRemoved and ValuesAdded Events that discard and add new views respectively. What is the best way to also set the selection state of the newly added UI elements if the old one was selected?

I could set up a flag on the controlling class before making the model changes that is checked in the ValuesAddedEvent handler, however this won't allow me to maintain the selection state on undo/redo of the modification. Undo/redo also doesn't appear to adopt the compound operation name list of the change that caused the original events so I can't check that either.

```
test('Compound Operation Names in undo', function() {
  doc.getModel().beginCompoundOperation('a name');
  doc.getModel().getRoot().set('key','value');
  doc.getModel().endCompoundOperation();
  var vc = function(event) {
    deepEqual(event.compoundOperationNames, ['a name']);
  };
  doc.getModel().getRoot().addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUE_CHANGED, vc);
  doc.getModel().undo();
  doc.getModel().getRoot().removeEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUE_CHANGED, vc);
});
```

Test fails with Expected: `['a name']`, Actual: `[]`

Comment: Are you persisting the selection state?  Or is it a per-user, session scoped thing?

Comment: It's per user the same way it would be with ordinary text. I guess it wouldn't do any harm to also put that state into the model.

Comment: Ok... I think I'm not understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you explain more clearly what you need to maintain as values are added or removed?

Comment: My model is a collaborative list of objects that are rendered in html as divs in a line. You select a div by clicking on it and then it gets a border around it. The selection state does not persist across reloads and is not shared with other users, i.e. not in the model. When you hit space bar, any selected value in the list will be removed and two new values will be added to the list at that index. The two new values are to be rendered as selected because the old one was. The problem is to know that the new objects should be selected when the new divs are added in the ValuesAddedEvent handler

Comment: That is to say, how do I know a given ValuesAddedEvent was due to this action instead of some other button that just adds a box to the end of the list, for example

Comment: I see.  Makes sense.  I think that compound operations with custom labels is probably the right way to do this.  But you are seeing that you don't get those labels back on undo?

Comment: Correct, I don't get the operation name in undo. I've added a test case in the question

Comment: OK, you are correct that the label does not persist in the undo stack. See other possibilities below.

Answer (score 1):

You could track the selected range in the model using IndexReferences.  This would have the side benefit of allowing you to display information to collaborators, if that makes sense in your application.

If you don't want to persist it, then I think you should be able to determine when you are in this situation by looking at the set of changes + the current selection.

If you have an ObjectChangedListener on the list, you will get an event that contains all of the changes within the compound operation.  If you have a set of changes that matches the behavior, and the index referenced is one currently selected then you know you are in this situation and can act according.

Comment: Thx. IndexReferences would work but would be pretty complicated as non-contiguous selections are supported. I can't check for the index being selected in the ObjectChanged (OC) listener because it was already removed when ValuesRemoved (VR) fired; and I can't wait until OC to do the removal because values can be removed in other actions. I can't just check for VR and VA in an OC because it's also possible to split an entry that isn't selected.I think I'll have to use IndexReferences or copy the selected state into a property named  `'<sessionId>-selected'` and ignore other sessions' selections